# Send push notifications/emails when a query/mutation happends in AppSync/Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync, aws-aurora-serverless

I am using AppSync with Aurora/RDS.
I would like that in some cases, when a query/mutation is sent to the db, then, after that, I want to send an email and push notification, but this should be detached from the query/mutation, that is, it does not matter if it fails or works. 
At the moment I see all these options:
Can you tell me which one I should use?

1. Create a query that calls a lambda function that sends the
   push/email and call it from the client once the actual
   query/mutation is done. I don't like this because the logic is in
   the client rather than the server. Seems easy to implement, and I
   guess it is easy to ignore the result of the second operation from a
   client point of view.
2. A variation of the previous one. Pack both operations in a single
   network request. With GraphQL, that is easy, but I don't want the
   client waits for the second operation. (Is it possible to create
   lambda functions that return immediately, like a trigger of other
   functions?)
3. Attach my queries/mutations to lambda functions instead of RDS
   directly. Then, those lambda functions call other lambda functions
   for notifications. Seems more difficult to program, but more
   micro-services architecture friendly. Probably this is the best one,
   not sure.
4. Use SQL triggers and call lambda functions from those triggers. I
   don't know if this is even possible. Researching...
5. Use pipelines resolvers. The first one is the query/mutation, the
   second one is the lambda function that sends the push/email. I would
   say this is a bad option because I don't want the client to wait for
   the second operation or manage the logic when the second resolver
   fails.
6. Amazon RDS Events: It appears it is possible to attach lambda
   functions to specific AWS RDS events.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds.html It
   seems it is about creating DBs, restoring... and that kind of
   things. I don't see anything like creating a row, updating a row...
   So, I discard this unless I am wrong.
7. Invoking a Lambda Function with an Aurora MySQL Stored Procedure
   CALL mysql.lambda_async (   lambda_function_ARN,lambda_function_input )
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html
   "For example, you might want to send a notification using Amazon
   Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) whenever a row is inserted
   into a specific table in your database." That is exactly what I am
   looking for. I like this idea, but I don't know if that is possible
   with Aurora Serverless. Researching... It seems it is not possible
   when using server-less:
   https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/a9szid/aurora_serverless_call_lambda/
8. Use step functions: No idea about how to use it.
9. Somehow, attach this lambda notification function to GraphQL/AppSync
   instead of the database, but I guess it is not a good idea because I
   need to read the database to the push notification token and the
   email of the use who is going to receive the notifications.

Which method do you recommend me? I am using amplify cli.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This may prove useful to you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html

Comment: Thanks but when using AppSync, you have to use Aurora Serverless, and your link is only about Aurora, it does not work with serverless :(

Comment: I face the same problem, I give up, it seems the best option is to use lambda function but I was looking for a way to do it "decoupled" from the main code. like a trigger. But it seems is not possible to create triggers directly from the resolvers

Comment: @eli.rodriguez check https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3106

Comment: @eli.rodriguez Using microservices is the correct approach, but too complex, I will use use a specific query to send push and emails, and pipelines to get info from the database and pass that to the lambda function, because accesing the database from the lambda is also a pain in the ass. Check pipilenes here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3321

Answer (score 2):

Currently AWS AppSync can only send notifications when the app is active. We are looking into implementation of the non active case.

If you want to send notifications when the app is not active, you can use the push notifications on iOS: silent push/interactive push or push notifications on Android.

If you want to send emails, voice/text message or notifications on phone when the app is not active, you can integrate with [Amazon Pinpiont](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/).